# Inserting Dates with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, date

I have a CSV file, which contains three dates:

```
    '2010-07-01','2010-08-05','2010-09-04'
```

When I try to bulk insert them...

```
    BULK INSERT [dbo].[STUDY]
        FROM 'StudyTable.csv' 
        WITH 
        ( 
            MAXERRORS = 0,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
        )
```

I get an error:

```
    Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (CREATED_ON).
```

So I'm assuming this is because I have an invalid date format. What is the correct format to use?

**EDIT**

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDY]
    (
        [CREATED_ON] DATE,
        [COMPLETED_ON] DATE,
        [AUTHORIZED_ON] DATE,
    }
```

Comment: Whats the data type on your table fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got quotes (') around your dates. Remove those and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your data file have a header record? If it does, obviously your table names will not be the correct data type, and will fail when SQL Server tries to INSERT them into your table. Try this:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[STUDY]
    FROM 'StudyTable.csv' 
    WITH 
    ( 
        MAXERRORS = 0,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        FIRSTROW = 2
    )
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) the BULK INSERT operation technically doesn't support skipping header records in the CSV file. You can either remove the header record or try the above. I don't have SQL Server in front of me at the moment, so I have not confirmed this works. YMMV.

Comment: No, no headers. There were originally, (exported from OpenOffice's version of Excel) but I removed them manually.